# Unsupported Wine version when trying to run Overwatch 2 on Lutris

Tags: wine, games, lutris

I'm running lutris-7.2-2-x86_64 on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and downloaded Overwatch 2 on Battle.net (Version 2.1.0.1.105995). When I press "Play" I get

> Unsupported Wine version. Please update to 7.0 or higher.

I'm lost at what to do, as it seems there is no newer lutris version.

Comment: Overwatch has a "garbage" rating on WineHQ. Overwatch 2 doesn't even have that. It's unrated.  Wine is probably not appropriate for this software. Petition the developer for a native Linux client. In the meantime, expect to need to install the software on a supported OS

Comment: Overwatch went without a problem for the few days I played it. I want to understand the error I'm confronted with. Is my Lutris not running on Wine 7?

Comment: Ergo I could try a newer wine version. I will do that and see if i can get it not conflicting with the one lutris uses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it running! The issue was indeed the Wine version. The version on which it runs is [Wine Caffee 7.18](https://github.com/bottlesdevs/wine/releases/tag/caffe-7.18). More detailed instructions can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/ryleu/aaef41c71dddd612c6bcf118c7870149). If you run into further issues, I recommend checking out the Lutris Discord community.